# Proof for multivariate Newton-Raphson method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

How can the [proof for Newton's method for a single variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_Raphson#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method) be extended to the multivariate version?

Forgive me if this is trivial, but I don't seem to get it. Any links or proofs would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright gives a proof of the multivariable form of Newton's method (ie, linesearch method based on sequence of gradients) using gradients of the function and the hessian matrix $\nabla^2f_k$.  Immediately, you need $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be twice continuously differentiable.  If the hessian is postive definite, you achieve quadratic convergence.

Comment: @yugtham Can you tell me where the proof is in the book? Here is the link : http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf , what chapter or  pages should I read?

Comment: Starts at the bottom of page 51 (book page) and goes to page 53.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say $x_0$ is a root. We must assume that the Jacobian matrix $Df(x_0)$ is invertible; otherwise the quadratic convergence may fail (as it does in the single-variable case, when $f'(x_0)=0$). Also assume that $f$ is $C^2$ smooth (consequently, $Df$ is Lipschitz continuous). Then at $x=x_0+h$, with $h$ small, we have 
$$f(x) = Df(x_0) h + O(\|h\|^2)\tag1$$
(second order Taylor expansion) and 
$$Df(x) = Df(x_0)   + O(\|h\|)\tag2$$
(Lipschitz continuity of $Df$). Since $Df(x_0)$ is invertible, (2) implies 
$$Df(x)^{-1} = Df(x_0)^{-1}   + O(\|h\|)\tag3$$
From (1) and (3),
$$\begin{split}x-(Df(x))^{-1}f(x) &= x_0+h - (Df(x_0)^{-1}   + O(\|h\|)) (Df(x_0) h + O(\|h\|^2))\\ & = x_0 +O(\|h\|^2) \end{split}$$
which is the desired quadratic convergence.

Comment: What is the O notation for? and how does (2) imply (3)?